# Including Vue Components as node modules in a nuxt vue/typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, import, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project that I recently migrated to typescript. I also have a seperate repo full of vue components that are imported as node modules into my nuxt project.
I have included them in my typescript class based SFC using `import Component from '@place/vue-component'`
When I try to run my app I get 500 errors with this message `render function or template not defined in component: Card` but the app does compile successfully.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but this is what worked for me:

In my vue.shim.d.ts file I needed to declare each import like this:

```
declare module "@place/vue-component" {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```

and in addition:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Then this was my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```